# Monogame Single Runtime Executable?

Tags: c#, installation, exe, monogame

I used to use a lot of Gamemaker, which gave the option of compressing your entire game into a single executable file, and I was wondering if there was any way to do the same in a C# project.

Me and some friends are making a game using Monogame, and I want to be able to export the project and send it to them without having them to un/install every time I send a new version. I've used ClickOnce, Visual Studio Setup Projects, and 7zip SFX installers before.

I thought about just sending a copy of the Release folder in a zip, which is totally doable, but if I wanted to take that (or any) archive and make it into an exe, how would I?

Is there any way to do this, or nah?

Comment: ILMerge..................or bake yourself using Manifest resource stream

Comment: You could WIX to make a MSI that will uninstall the old version and install the new one in a single step. You can configure manually which files to pick, where the content goes and so on.